# UseInMemoryDatabase for table storage

Tags: azure-table-storage, in-memory-database

Can we use UseInMemoryDatabase to add some tables in table storage in memory?

```
           var loadInMemoryDatabase = Configuration.GetValue<bool>("loadInMemoryDatabase");

           if (loadInMemoryDatabase)
           {
               servicesCollection.AddDbContext<PublishAppsContext>(options =>
                   options.UseInMemoryDatabase()
               );               
           }
```

Comment: What happens when you try?